# How to avoid the entire request being logged every time using pino?

Tags: node.js, logging

I am new to nodejs and decided to use the `pino` logger in my application. Here is the code snippet showing how I am using it:

```
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger');
const { LOGLEVEL } = require('../config.js');

// Constructs a Pino Instance
const logger = pino({
  level: LOGLEVEL || 'trace',
  prettyPrint: { levelFirst: true, colorize: true, ignore: 'pid' },
});
// Construct an express middleware using the above pino instance
const expressLogger = expressPino({ logger });

module.exports = { logger, expressLogger };
```

Now, every time I do `req.log.debug(config['abc'])`, the entire request body gets logged, thus making the logs very cumbersome to read. For every such `log` statement, the output looks like this:

```
DEBUG [1610445271782] (on blserver-org1): sku=FIN01  Query String
req: {
  "id": 1,
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "/ifo_params?sku=FIN01",
  "headers": {
    "channel-name": "mychannel",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVmOTcxMmEwODczMTcyMGQ2NmZkNGEyYTU5MmU0ZGZjMmI1ZGU1OTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.QlHxLrxcfxUmGK_Q193RdQSIBsoHly66CZDTWdRdyfZNAn-wH13el41ILnAj3YqVWgAFJY8u4BcFgZYePCujIO2gKFsM0WUs2M-a7CsMcDaWpqrQyVsfalRoYMDsk1DJypaevuKV8O4IbmdkgCbS8HmYO-dk99LRcwwYKs_vVnNBO4bTv5FFzMLh-DXrVfVBKk23Qem7JN5lX9UU6RZ-4WAVN-pN-TR5uRuF2koWjCoa90CKNhYOzKW1zeN904f1rCeuY0a4R4faFYMNAlkxslBpVSKaXCkSBXOSCjVykp611Ay6EQBkrpqbD1zHvv6eEfaaMyOzjlH3DzDye-vfMQ",
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "aab26357-78ff-4899-8509-7918ca9a65c4",
    "host": "localhost:3000",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "114"
  }
}
```

I tried changing the log levels but that doesn't help. Can someone please tell me how to tell pino to not log the entire request every time.

Comment: What's is `config['abc']`? Is it the `req.body` from express that you are referring to?

Comment: config['abc'] is just an example to show that I want to log something specific. Yes, `req.body` is from express

Comment: Then  `req.body` is pretty big in and by itself. If you want specific information you have to extract it out of the object. Such as `req.body.id`

Comment: Yes, `req.body` is big and that is what I am trying to avoid being logged. But whenever I do req.log.debug(....), the entire request body does get logged. I am not logging req.body explicitly

Comment: Then what are you logging ?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do it using information in this [bug report on pino-http](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-http/issues/5)

The gist is to override the serializer for the request by including the following configuration option when initializing pino

```
serializers: {
  req: (req) => ({
    id: req.id,
    method: req.method,
    url: req.url
  })
}
```

Of course you can add or remove additional fields from the req.  You can also do the same thing with the response if you use the `res` property.

Comment: Is this modifying the request? In the bug report you mentioned, they say it will modify the original req object.

Comment: just to mention that one can also return not objects, but just a string. E.g.: `req => \`> ${req.method} ${req.url}\` ` and `res => \`< ${res.statusCode} ${res.headers['content-type']}\` `

Answer (score 3):

Add them to **ignore** key when constructing your Pino instance.Here:

```js
// Constructs a Pino Instance
const logger = pino({
  level: LOGLEVEL || 'trace',
  prettyPrint: {
    levelFirst: true,
    colorize: true,
    ignore: 'pid,req,res',
  },
});
```

Take a look: https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty#options

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar. I wanted to log the whole request info in the automatic logs like `request completed`, but not when I am doing other logs in the application. All I had to do was pass the `quietReqLogger: true` to the `pinoHttp` options, it still keeps the `reqId` property, which can be used to track the other info if needed.

```
LoggerModule.forRoot({
    pinoHttp: {
        genReqId: () => randomUUID(),
        quietReqLogger: true,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the same in `Nest js` with this approach:

```js
pinoHttp: {
        autoLogging: false,
        transport: {
          target: 'pino-pretty',
          options: {
            singleLine: true,
          },
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
export function getChildLogger(req: Request) {
const id = req.id;
const logger = pino({
    level: 'info',  // what ever log level is required here

})
return logger.child({ reqId: id })
}
```

Then use it like this

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {    
const logger = getChildLogger(req);
logger.info("This is test log")
res.json({ status: "ok" })
});
```

May be not the best solution. But works :D